# The existence of Nash equilibria for two-player zero-sum games

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory

I am studying zero-sum games from Robert Kleinberg's [notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs683/2007sp/). In these notes, the author defines a normal form game as follows:

> A normal form game is specified by
>
> - A set of $\mathcal{I}$ players
> - For each player $i \in \mathcal{I}$, a set of $A_{i}$ strategies.
> - For each player $i \in \mathcal{I}$ a payoff function
>
> $$ u_{i} \: : \prod_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_{i} \to \mathbb{R} $$

and then goes on to specify a two-player zero-sum game:

> A two-player zero-sum game is one in which $\mathcal{I} = \{1, 2\}$
> and $u_{2}(a_{1}, a_{2}) = -u_{1}(a_{1}, a_{2})$ for all pure strategy
> profiles $(a_{1}, a_{2})$.

Mixed strategies are defined in the standard fashion:

> For a finite set $A$ let $\Delta(A)$ denote the probability simplex
> generated by $A$ i.e.
>
> $$ \Delta(A) = \left\{p : A \to [0, 1]  \:\: \bigg| \:\: \sum_{a \in
>  A} p(a) = 1 \right\} $$
>
> The payoff functions for mixed strategies are extended naturally from the payoffs
> for pure strategies:
>
> $$ u_{i}(p_{1}, p_{2}, \dots, p_{|\mathcal{I}|}) = \sum_{a} u_{i}(a)p_{1}(a_{1})p_{2}(a_{2})\dots p_{|\mathcal{I}|}(a_{|\mathcal{I}|})$$
>
> where the sum runs over all pure strategy profiles $a = (a_{1}, a_{2},
> \dots, a_{|\mathcal{I}|})$.

The main focus of the notes are von Neumann's minimax theorem. In the discussion, the author makes the following assertion:

> Note that sets $B_{1} = \text{arg}\max_{p}\min_{q} u_{1}(p, q)$ and
> $B_{2} = \text{arg}\min_{q}\max_{p}u_{1}(p, q)$ are nonempty. This
> follows from compactness of $\Delta(A_{1})$ and $\Delta(A_{2})$, the
> continuity of $u_{1}$ and the finiteness of $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$.

My question is rather simple. Why is this the case? This is my attempt so far:

I will only consider the case of $B_{1}$ in what follows.

$u_{1}$ is jointly continuous in $p$ and $q$, implying that the function $u_{1}(p) = \min_{q} u_{1}(p, q)$ is well-defined since $\Delta(A_{2})$ is compact. As a result, $u_{1}(p)$ is continuous (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458601/show-that-hx-max-fx-y-y-in-0-1-is-continuous)). Hence, the maximum of $u_{1}(p)$ is attained and hence the $\text{arg}\max$ set is nonempty, which is exactly the claim we wanted to prove.

Is this logic correct? If so, then why do we need a finiteness assumption on $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$? Maybe we don't, but the proof is made easier with this additional assumption?

Comment: every finite set is compact, so my guess is the finite assumption probably yields the compactness of $\Delta(A_1)$ and $\Delta(A_2)$?

Comment: So the set $\Delta(A_{2})$ is the set of probability distributions with support $A_{2}$. I guess the interpretation is that each element of $A_{2}$ can be mapped to its corresponding degenerate distribution. Thus, $\Delta(A_{2})$ is basically the convex hull of $A_{2}$. So I guess what you say is true as I imagine the convex hull of a set is compact if and only if the underlying set is compact (at least for Euclidean spaces).